# How do I change a price when multiple items are selected?

Tags: javascript, html, price

I am doing a project (school) and need help with JavaScript programming. The code can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/zvov1jpr/3/

HTML:

```html
<script src="java.js"></script>
<div id="formular">
  <div id="formulartekst">
    <form>

      <h2 class="formskrift">Order Hot Food</h2>
      <p class="kroner">$39 / $29 when 3 or more checked</p>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p1" onclick="totalIt()" /> Monday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p2" onclick="totalIt()" /> Tuesday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p3" onclick="totalIt()" /> Wednesday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p4" onclick="totalIt()" /> Thursday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p5" onclick="totalIt()" /> Friday
      <label>
        <br> Total
        <input value="$0.00" readonly type="text" id="total" />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Order">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function totalIt() {
    var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].checked) {
          total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
        }
     }
     document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

When I check boxes it automatically adds up the price (for some reason it doesn't on JSFiddle but it works fine on my website). However, I need it so when I have 3 or more boxes checked, it has to change the price to $29 pr. Check instead of $39.

Comment: When selecting 3 or more, total has to be $29 per day and otherwise $39 per day. Right?

Comment: And, the function will work on jsfiddle is it is `window.totalIt= function()` instead of `function totalIt()`

Comment: Check following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zvov1jpr/4/). reason why its not working is because, in JSFiddle, there are options to load JS in different section. Your code is getting loaded in head. Make it to load in body. In JSFiddle, you see `JAVASCRIPT` label, click on it and change `load Type` to `No wrap - in <body>`

Comment: I got it to work, thank you.

Comment: I ran into a different problem. Code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/u0y7aoct/
When I check the top 5 boxes the price adjusts itself when I check 3 or more. However if I check any of the below 5 boxes the price overwrites.

I need the total price showing, but right now they are acting as two different. Also desserts should not have a discount when 3 or more are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a small JSFiddle issue that I have already commented about.

Apart from that you can use querySelectors to reduce code.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zvov1jpr/6/)

```js
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='product']:checked")
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" +
    (input.length * (input.length > 2 ? 29 : 39))
}
```

```html
<script src="java.js"></script>
<div id="formular">
  <div id="formulartekst">
    <form>

      <h2 class="formskrift">Order Hot Food</h2>
      <p class="kroner">$39 / $29 when 3 or more checked</p>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p1" onclick="totalIt()" />Monday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p2" onclick="totalIt()" />Tuesday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p3" onclick="totalIt()" />Wednesday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p4" onclick="totalIt()" />Thursday
      <br>
      <input name="product" value="39" type="checkbox" id="p5" onclick="totalIt()" />Friday
      <label>
        <br>Total
        <input value="$0.00" readonly type="text" id="total" />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Order">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
function totalIt(){

   var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
     if (input[i].checked) {
       total+= 1;
     }
   }
   if(total>=3){
   document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + (total*29).toFixed(2);
   }
   else{
   document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + (total*39).toFixed(2);
   }
```